# Get computed value from two observable arrays

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I read a lot of threads and there isn't enough information how can I compute two observable arrays and track add/remove on them and update computed observable, because now computed just updates once and never changes while there is already lot changes made to those two.

Here is [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skmasq/YSk8E/1/)

Here is code behind it:

```
var VM = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.first = ko.observableArray([{
        Id: 1,
        name: "john"
    }, {
        Id: 3,
        name: "steve"
    }, {
        Id: 5,
        name: "roger"
    }]);

    self.second = ko.observableArray([{
        Id: 2,
        name: "laker"
    }, {
        Id: 4,
        name: "don"
    }, {
        Id: 6,
        name: "idiot"
    }]);

    self.both = ko.computed(function () {
        return self.first().concat(self.second());
    });

    self.removePerson = function (v) {
        (self.first().indexOf(v) !== -1) ? ko.utils.arrayRemoveItem(self.first(), self.first()[self.first().indexOf(v)]) : ((self.second().indexOf(v) !== -1) ? ko.utils.arrayRemoveItem(self.second(), self.second()[self.second().indexOf(v)]) : console.log("Item doesnt exist"));
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new VM());
```

---

### Question

**How can I make `computed` update after every change to `first` or `second`?**

Comment: An [alot](http://hyperboleandahalf.blogspot.com/2010/04/alot-is-better-than-you-at-everything.html) of threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computed is fine, your `removePerson` is working incorrectly.

So don't see the changes on the UI because when you are using `ko.utils.arrayRemoveItem` it removes the items from the underlying arrays so KO won't know about the changes so it does not update the computed.

One way to fix it to call the `valueHasMutated()` on your arrays after the remove which will trigger the computed change. ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9QbVT/))

Or you can use the `myObservableArray.remove(someItem)` method (see [doc](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html)) instead:

```
self.removePerson = function (v) {
    (self.first().indexOf(v) !== -1) 
    ?  self.first.remove(v) 
    :  self.second.remove(v)
}
```

Demo [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/sA6C4/)

Comment: Thank god your alive. Have a nice day.